# Correlation between variable and variable conditioned on the sign agreement

Tags: correlation, covariance, multivariate-normal-distribution

Suppose I have two variables X1 and X2, following a bivariate standard normal distribution with a correlation coefficient of 0.2, if I create a new variable X3 that is equal to X2 if X1 and X2 have the same sign and zero otherwise, is there an analytical expression (i.e. discard simulation approach) for the correlation of X1 and X3?